# How to chain folders like a java packages?

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes IntelliJ shows me folders chained, sometimes not. How can I chain folders? How can I chain folders like a packages?

[image: not chained]
[image: chained]

Answer (score 0):

That'd be the Flatten Packages option that comes under the Project view cog.
[image]